# How can I edit these reports (see the pic)?

Tags: account, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I'm trying to edit these reports, but I can't  click on them like in the pic. Besides that, I can't see them in the tab "Reports"or Setups...

Is it private to some user even though I am an administrator?

P.s: "Number" is a custom field in Account.

P.s 2: "Total Opp" and "Test" are reports, not report types. I can't access and I want to edit them

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] you post to clarify:  are you trying to edit a custom report type?  Please describe exactly what you are trying to do.  Your screenshot is not showing any reports or report types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot view reports that are under the user's [Private reports folder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317823&type=1&mode=1).  You can use below SOQL query to locate reports in private folders.

```
SELECT DeveloperName,FolderName,Id,Name,OwnerId FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate
```

You would get list of reports along with User Id and since you are system admin you should be able to login As with that specific user and make changes accordingly.

Check more details if you want to delete reports saved in private folders [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_dashboards_allPrivate_delete.htm).

Thanks